# Tooltips don't show with Chartjs V2.0.2

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, chart.js

I have a line chart like this:
[image: Line chart]

The tooltips are not showing.
Here is what initializes the chart:

```
function initializeLineChart() {
    var graph = document.getElementById('LineChart').getContext('2d');
    var chart = new Chart(graph, {
        type: "line",
        data: LineUserData,
        options: {
            tooltips: {
                mode: 'label'
            }
        }
    });
}
```

`LineUserData` is something like this:

```
LineUserData = {
    labels: ["Janeiro","Fevereiro","Março","Abril","Maio","Junho","Julho","Agosto","Setembro","Outubro","Novembro","Dezembro"],
    datasets: [{"label":"Loja 2","backgroundColor":"#1C154A16","borderColor":"#1C154A","borderWidth":0,"pointBorderColor":"#1C154A16","pointBackgroundColor":"#1C154A","data":[0,12,0,2,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0]},{"label":"Sem Vendedor","backgroundColor":"#36388A16","borderColor":"#36388A","borderWidth":0,"pointBorderColor":"#36388A16","pointBackgroundColor":"#36388A","data":[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]}],
}
```

It appears this error on the console:

[image: Error]

Comment: Cant seem to reproduce: https://jsfiddle.net/Leelenaleee/reu97z5a/1/

Comment: I changed the pointBorderColor and backgroundColor to rgb and it worked. https://codepen.io/baratafeyo/pen/YzxbBbR

Comment: But it doesn't work on my webapp

Comment: Now the error is: "Unable to parse color from string "left""